# Properties of Jordan Measure Sets (Measure Theory)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I've been having a bit of trouble with Exercise 1.1.6 in Terence Tao's book "An Introduction to Measure Theory". Picture of the problem can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMBCE.png).

There's a theorem (in the form of a previous exercise), that seems to be helpful. Pic [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMaW4.png). I tried applying (1)->(2) from this theorem with $A_1$ ⊂ E ⊂ $B_1$ and $A_2$ ⊂ F ⊂ $B_2$, but to no avail. Any tips on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: It would perhaps be better to write out the information in your pictures here, so that we don't have to follow links. You may have a higher chance of answers that way.

Comment: Hint: prove that $E$  is Jordan measurable $\Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon>0\ \exists$ elementary sets $A\subseteq E\subseteq B$ such that $m(B\setminus A)<\epsilon$.

Comment: You can find the proof here: https://math.solverer.com/library/terence_tao/an_introduction_to_measure_theory/exercise_1-1-6